# How do I change IMEs on device for an espresso test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am looking for a way to change the IME on my testing device. I have a keyboard that is a requirement for my application. My application currently takes the user to the settings app to enable and select the keyboard. This is done with a button that contains the following code.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Espresso seems to get lost when that activity launches. What is going on?
I get an error like this.

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
```

Also I heard rumors from [GTAC 2014](http://youtu.be/aHcmsK9jfGU?t=17m35s) of a TestUtil for this? Anyone know how to get this library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UI Automator? That way you can perform tests that span different applications.